# FFmpeg, av_frame_free - Does not free all memory allocated by av_frame_clone

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to clone **AVFrame**. For this purpose, I call **av_frame_clone** function.
Then I want to free all memory allocated by old AVFrame. For this purpose I call **av_frame_free** function. Memory which is pointer by data is not freed by **av_frame_free** function. So what is the correct way of cloning and deleting a AVFrame in ffmpeg ?

Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for *av_frame_clone()* say:

> Create a new frame that references the same data as src. This is a
>   shortcut for av_frame_alloc()+av_frame_ref().

Those for *av_frame_free()* say:

> Free the frame and any dynamically allocated objects in it, e.g.
>   extended_data. If the frame is reference counted, it will be
>   unreferenced first.

So, combining these two functions looks correct.

What happens with the original frame?  Probably it needs to an unref?

Comment: I think he intended "cloning" as duplicating two av frames as completely separate from each other (having separate buffer). Since `av_frame_clone()` seems doesn't do that, insteads shares buffer and increases ref count.